# I am getting a PHP syntax error, unexpected ')' on line 23 in this code, can't see the issue

Tags: php

new to PHP so I'm struggling to see why this is a syntax error, a correction and some advice would be great, thanks! Code below:

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\User;
use App\Chatkit;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class UserController extends Controller
{
    public function create(Request $request, Chatkit $chatkit)
    {
        $data = $request->validate([
                                   'name' => 'required|string|max:255',
                                   'password' => 'required|string|min:6',
                                   'email' => 'required|string|email|max:255|unique:users',
                                   ]);

        $data['chatkit_id'] = str_slug($data['email'], '_');

        $response = $chatkit->createUser([
                                         'id' => $data['chatkit_id'],
                                         'name' => $data['name']
                                         );

        if ($response['status'] !== 201) {
            return response()->json(['status' => 'error'], 400);
        }

        return response()->json(User::create($data));
    }
}
```

Comment: there is a , too much

Comment: I don't see a syntax error here. Can you post the surrounding code? Syntax errors tend to be generated by the preceding lines.

Comment: @Bernhard Arrays may have a trailing `,`

Comment: You forgot too close the outer array in your `createUser` function call. Using an IDE/Editor with syntax highlighting and error checking makes it a lot easier to find typos such as this.

Comment: `$response =` no closing `]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's here:

```
    $response = $chatkit->createUser([
                                     'id' => $data['chatkit_id'],
                                     'name' => $data['name']
                                     );
  //--------------------------------^
```

You need a `]` making it:

```
    $response = $chatkit->createUser([
                                     'id' => $data['chatkit_id'],
                                     'name' => $data['name']
                                    ]);
```